# Cheerio Scraping with Bluebird Promise

Tags: node.js, bluebird, cheerio, request-promise

Why this code is not working? I get

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

**test.js**

```
'use strict';

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request-promise');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

module.exports = {
    get: function () {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var options = {
                uri: 'https://www.example.com',
                transorm: function (body) {
                    return cheerio.load(body);
                }
            };

            request(options)
                .then(function ($) {
                    // Error happens here
                    $('#mydivid').text();
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you jquery included if this is a frontend code?

Comment: The $ is just a placeholder for cheerio.load(body);, I'm not using jQuery here (even if cheerio is somehow similar).

Comment: try replacing $ with `cheerio`

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another look, and  i found the issue. Your `options` object is as follows:

```
 var options = {
                uri: 'https://www.example.com',
                transorm: function (body) {
                    return cheerio.load(body);
                }
 };
```

You used `transorm` instead of `transform`. Hence its returning string of html content instead of `cheerio.load(body)`. change it to `transform` it'll work.

```
 var options = {
                uri: 'https://www.example.com',
                transform: function (body) {
                    return cheerio.load(body);
                }
 };
```

Comment: This way the function "transform" becomes useless. You just moved the logic  .

Comment: Since you didn't accept my answer, i wanted to have another look. guess what i found the issue. see my updated answer.